# Installing Python Modules in Windows

Tags: python

I am new to Python and want to learn it. I am trying to install python27 modules but getting following error. I am using cmd to install these modules. May be I am doing something wrong and not aware of it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to set a version of matplotlib like this: `pip install matplotlib==1.5.0`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Does your computer run behind a proxy? Because **ConnectTimeoutError** implies a network problem. If so you can try `pip install matplotlib --proxy [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port`

Comment: That's true. Is there a way to install it using exe file just like we can do to install libraries in R? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed matplotlib yesterday, here are the basic procedure:

1 Install python **32bit** if you want to make it easier to install matplotlib

2 download the **exe installer** from matplotlib project page and click install

3 done